# Div border cut off when behind another div

Tags: css, z-index

I am having trouble getting the top of the border to show up of a div that is behind another div. It is currently cut off, but I'd like to get it to show behind the skills tag. Is this possible? Thank you!!

```
#skills{
width: 75px;
height: 40px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1em;
position: relative;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;    
line-height: 38px;
background-color: #ffe8eb;
float: left;

}

#box {
width: 84%;
max-width: 500px;
height: 200px;
margin-top: 40px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `box-sizing: border-box` for both of those and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to get it to show behind the skills tag. Is this possible?

The `z-index` property specifies the order of an element as they appear in the DOM (with the lowest element down at the same hierarchy level always appearing on top). When elements overlap, the `z-index` value determines which one covers the other. `z-index` only effects elements that have a position value other than the default value. To create the affect you're wanting, you need to add a lesser `z-index` value to `#skills`, like this:

```
#skills{
  width: 75px;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;    
  line-height: 38px;
  background-color: #ffe8eb;
  float: left;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

Or change the `z-index` value of `#box` from -1 to 1. Here's a fiddle example for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/dconymaf/

Answer (score 1):

your `#skills` element does not have the `z-index` property set, meaning it will default to `auto`, which will check the parent element's z-index to calculate it, My advice would be to set both elements index to be sure:

```
#skills{
width: 75px;
height: 40px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1em;
position: relative;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;    
line-height: 38px;
background-color: #ffe8eb;
float: left;
z-index: 0;
}

#box {
width: 84%;
max-width: 500px;
height: 200px;
margin-top: 40px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: taxicala, thank you for your response! unfortunately, that did not work. #box is definitely behind #skills, but the content of #box gets cut off where it is behind #skills.

Comment: just kidding. i got it to work by changing #skills to z-index: 1; and taking away the z-index for #box.